# RSA / MD5 Digital Signatures - Need help reversing existing code using CryptVerifySignature

Tags: c#

I've inherited a project that is supposed to perform two functions:
a) Validate Digital Signature
b) Create Digital Signature

My struggle is, I simply do not know enough about validating / signing digital signatures.
I do have the validation code and it works as expected.   I'm struggling to re-create the "signing" portion.

In short, we've got a huge number of files, small size, with the digital signature stored inside.  An example would be, first 150 bytes are specific to the company while the remaining belongs to the digital signature (seemingly always 0x40 in length).

Here is the "Validation" code, that works just fine:

```
    static readonly string pszContainer = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-470f-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    static readonly string pszProvider = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0";
    static readonly byte[] pbData = new byte[] { 0x0, 0x0, ....};

    static bool VerifiyFile(string lpFileName)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(lpFileName);
        byte[] pbSignature = new byte[0x40];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(fileBytes, fileBytes.Length - 0x40, pbSignature, 0, 0x40);

        if (InitialiseUpdateCryptoAPI())
        {
            IntPtr hProv = default(IntPtr);
            IntPtr hHash = default(IntPtr);
            IntPtr hPubKey = default(IntPtr);
            int bufferLen = (fileBytes.Length - 0x40);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(fileBytes, 0, buffer, 0, bufferLen);

            if (Crypto.CryptAcquireContext(ref hProv, pszContainer, pszProvider, Crypto.PROV_RSA_FULL, 0))
                if (Crypto.CryptImportKey(hProv, pbData, 0x54, default(IntPtr), 0, ref hPubKey))
                    if (Crypto.CryptCreateHash(hProv, Crypto.CALG_MD5, default(IntPtr), 0, ref hHash))
                        if (Crypto.CryptHashData(hHash, buffer, bufferLen, 0))
                            if (Crypto.CryptVerifySignature(hHash, pbSignature, 0x40, hPubKey, null, 0))
                                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

So from this, I learned two things, we seemingly always expect the Signature to be 0x40 in length (so far, it holds true to a few files I've tested/verified) and we store the Sig at the end of the file-specific data.

*I did remove the actual values for pszContainer & pbData as they're specific to our company.*

..for the life of me, I can not reproduce a signature that matches an existing file's signature;  What I've tried doing is taking data from an existing file (minus the valid signature) and tried reproducing the exact same sign.

```
        IntPtr hCryptProv = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr hKey = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr hXchgKey = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr hHash = IntPtr.Zero;

        byte[] pbSignature = new byte[] { ... };
        byte[] data = new byte[] { ... };

        int dwSignlen = pbSignature.Length;

        if (Crypto.CryptAcquireContext(ref hCryptProv, pszContainer, pszProvider, Crypto.PROV_RSA_FULL, 0))
            if (Crypto.CryptImportKey(hCryptProv, pbData, pbData.Length, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref hXchgKey))
                if (Crypto.CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, Crypto.CALG_MD5, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref hHash))
                    if (Crypto.CryptHashData(hHash, data, data.Length, 0))
                        if (Crypto.CryptSignHash(hHash, Crypto.AT_SIGNATURE, null, 0, pbSignature, ref dwSignlen))
                            Console.WriteLine("pbSignature is the hash signature");

        Crypto.CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        hHash = IntPtr.Zero;
```

...I dont know enough about how this works to understand whats wrong / missing.  We fired the guy who implemented this and lost most of his *work*;    FWIW, The **Crypto** object is an implementation of wincrypt;

Comment: You cannot produce secure 64 byte RSA signatures. That's be a 512 bit modulus, which even a hobbyist can easily break. And of course MD5's weak collision resistance is often dangerous as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!   I think what we're missing is the private key used to sign these files.    From the way your reply sounds - it might not be too hard to brute force our way back to the private key - does that sound right?